# android parcelable referencing another parcelable circular dependence

Tags: android, loops, stack-overflow, parcelable, chain

Rather simple scenario really, but I could not find anything related on Google so here goes:

```
class ContainerClass implements Parcelable {
  List<ItemClass> _items;
  (...)

  public void writeToParcel( Parcel p, int args ) {
    p.writeList( _items );
    (...)
  }
}

class ItemClass implements Parcelable {
  ContainerClass _containerRef;      
  (...)

  public void writeToParcel( Parcel p, int args ) {
    p.writeParcelable( _containerRef );
    (...)
  }      
}
```

This will inevitably loop and overflow the stack.

My question: How am I supposed to deal with a situation where I have to pass an object of the above types through to a new Activity.

(For CommonsWare) Parcelable implementation does indeed not seem to check for, and avoid circular dependencies. 
Stacktrace with classnames replaced by above names:

```
08-12 10:17:45.233    5590-5590/com.package E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at com.package.ContainerClass.writeToParcel(ContainerClass.java:139)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
        at com.package.ItemClass.writeToParcel(ItemClass.java:182)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1173)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:622)
        at com.package.ContainerClass.writeToParcel(ContainerClass.java:144)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
        at com.package.ItemClass.writeToParcel(ItemClass.java:182)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1173)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:622)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been pondering some more and come up with two workarounds useful if anyone else is in the same boat:

1) (Inspired by CommonsWare)
Put a flag on each part of the chain to indicate direction
Up the heirarchy is lossy in the sense that all items to the ContainerClass cannot be restored.

```
class ContainerClass implements Parcelable {
  boolean _parcelableDownHeirarchy = true;
  List<ItemClass> _items;
  (...)

  private ContainerClass( Parcel in ) {
    _items = in.readArrayList( ItemClass.class.getClassLoader() );
    (...)

    if ( _parcelableDownHierarchy ) {
      for ( int i = 0; i < _items.size(); i++ ) 
        _items.get( i ).set_container( this );
    }          
  }

  public void writeToParcel( Parcel p, int args ) {
    p.writeByte( (byte)_parcelableDownHierarchy ? 1 : 0 );
    if ( _parcelableDownHeirarchy )
      p.writeList( _items );

    (...)
  }
}


class ItemClass implements Parcelable {
  boolean _parcelableDownHeirarchy = true;
  ContainerClass _containerRef;      
  (...)

  private ItemClass( Parcel in ) {
    if ( !_parcelableDownHeirarchy ) {
      _containerRef = in.readParcelable( ContainerClass.class.getClassLoader() );
      //Won't contain item in it's _items list.          
    }
  }

  public void writeToParcel( Parcel p, int args ) {
    p.writeByte( (byte)_parcelableDownHierarchy ? 1 : 0 );
    if ( !_parcelableDownHeirarchy ) //Up the heirarchy
      p.writeParcelable( _containerRef );

    (...)
  }      
}
```

2) Hackish workaround, employing a static hash table, granted each object can be uniquely identified by it's parcelable attributes. (In my case I have the primary key in my database in the objects).

```
class ContainerClass implements Parcelable {
  //Leave be
}


class ItemClass implements Parcelable {
  HaspMap<Long, ContainerClass> _parents = new HashMap<Long, ContainerClass>();
  ContainerClass _containerRef;      
  (...)

  public long get_PKhash() { /* Return unique identifier */ }

  private ItemClass( Parcel in ) {
    (...)
    assertTrue( (_containerRef = _parents.remove( get_PKhash() )) != null );
  }

  public void writeToParcel( Parcel p, int args ) {
    (...)//Don't write _containerRef
    _parents.put( this.get_PKhash, _containerRef );
  }      
}
```

Comment: I ended up implementing number 2.

Answer (score 9):

> This will inevitably loop and overflow the stack.

AFAIK, the parceling process does not handle [circular object graphs](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11047). I just filed [an issue to get this better documented](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58865).

One workaround is to not do `p.writeParcelable( _containerRef );`. Instead, in `ContainerClass`, in your `ContainerClass(Parcel in)` constructor (or however your `CREATOR` is handling it), after reading in your `_items` list, iterate over that list and tell each child about its parent.

Comment: That workaround would be great if I had to a ContainerClass through. Unfortunately it is a collection of ItemClass instances I have to pass to an activity.
While I could do the reverse and not p.writeList as I don't really need that information in this part of my program, that implementation causes problems in other parts when "Parseled" ContainerClass instances will not have the _items.