# Circular reference of parcelable objects

Tags: java, android, arraylist, parcelable

I've searching a lot about pass objects of type ArrayList  but I have not found something useful to solve my problem. This is the problem:

I have a class Vertex (which implements Parcelable) that have 4 attributes: name (String), minDistance (double), previous (Vertex) and an ArrayList of adjacencies (ArrayList of Edges).

I also have a class Edge (which implements Parcelable) with 3 atributes: from (Vertex), target(Vertex) and weight (double).

In my MainActivity I got an ArrayList of vertex (where each one have an ArrayList of Edges) and I want to pass to another activity my ArrayList.In this moment I have an StackOverflowError.

Class Vertex.java

```
   public class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex>, Parcelable {
    public final String name;
    public List<Edge> adjacencies = new ArrayList<Edge>();
    public double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    public Vertex previous;

    public Vertex(String argName) {
        name = argName;
    }

    public Vertex(Parcel in) {
        this.name = in.readString();
        this.minDistance=in.readDouble();
        Object[]aristas= in.readArray(Edge.class.getClassLoader());
        setAdjacencies(aristas);
    }

    public void addEdge(Edge e) {
        adjacencies.add(e);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public int compareTo(Vertex other) {
        return Double.compare(minDistance, other.minDistance);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeDouble(minDistance);     
        Object[] edgesArray = adjacencies.toArray();
        dest.writeArray(edgesArray);

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Vertex> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Vertex>() {
        public Vertex createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Vertex(in);
        }

        public Vertex[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Vertex[size];
        }
    };

    public void setAdjacencies(Object[] edges) {
        for (Object edge : edges) {
            if (edge instanceof Edge) {
                adjacencies.add((Edge) edge);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Class Edge.java

```
   public class Edge implements Parcelable {

    private Vertex from;
    private Vertex target;
    private double weigth;

    public Edge(Vertex from, Vertex target, double weight) {
        this.target = target;
        this.weigth = weight;
        this.from = from;
    }

    public Edge(Parcel in) {
        this.weigth=in.readDouble();
        this.target=(Vertex) in.readParcelable(getClass().getClassLoader());
        this.from=(Vertex) in.readParcelable(getClass().getClassLoader());  
    }

    public Vertex getTarget() {
        return target;
    }

    public void setTarget(Vertex target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    public double getWeigth() {
        return weigth;
    }

    public void setWeigth(double weigth) {
        this.weigth = weigth;
    }

    public Vertex getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(Vertex from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getFrom().toString() + " -> " + weigth + " -> "
                + getTarget().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dest.writeDouble(weigth);
        dest.writeParcelable( target,flags);
        dest.writeParcelable(from, flags);

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Edge> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Edge>() {
        public Edge createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Edge(in);
        }

        public Edge[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Edge[size];
        }
    };

}
```

I'd really appreciate your help

Thank you

I forgot to show the way I'm sending and receiving the parcelable objects:

To send (Fragment.java):

```
i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("LIST_VERTEX", ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getListaVertex());
```

To receive (ResultActivity.java):

```
nodos = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("LIST_VERTEX");
```

Note: ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getListaVertex() is an ArrayList of Vertex objects

LOGCAT:

11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939): java.lang.StackOverflowError
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeString(Parcel.java:513)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.Vertex.writeToParcel(Vertex.java:56)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.EdgesList.writeToParcel(EdgesList.java:48)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.Vertex.writeToParcel(Vertex.java:58)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.EdgesList.writeToParcel(EdgesList.java:48)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.Vertex.writeToParcel(Vertex.java:58)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.EdgesList.writeToParcel(EdgesList.java:48)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.Vertex.writeToParcel(Vertex.java:58)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.EdgesList.writeToParcel(EdgesList.java:48)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.Vertex.writeToParcel(Vertex.java:58)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.EdgesList.writeToParcel(EdgesList.java:48)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.Vertex.writeToParcel(Vertex.java:58)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.EdgesList.writeToParcel(EdgesList.java:48)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.Vertex.writeToParcel(Vertex.java:58)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.EdgesList.writeToParcel(EdgesList.java:48)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.Vertex.writeToParcel(Vertex.java:58)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.EdgesList.writeToParcel(EdgesList.java:48)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.Vertex.writeToParcel(Vertex.java:58)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.EdgesList.writeToParcel(EdgesList.java:48)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.Vertex.writeToParcel(Vertex.java:58)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.EdgesList.writeToParcel(EdgesList.java:48)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.Vertex.writeToParcel(Vertex.java:58)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.EdgesList.writeToParcel(EdgesList.java:48)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.Vertex.writeToParcel(Vertex.java:58)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.EdgesList.writeToParcel(EdgesList.java:48)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.Vertex.writeToParcel(Vertex.java:58)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.EdgesList.writeToParcel(EdgesList.java:48)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.Vertex.writeToParcel(Vertex.java:58)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.EdgesList.writeToParcel(EdgesList.java:48)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.Vertex.writeToParcel(Vertex.java:58)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.EdgesList.writeToParcel(EdgesList.java:48)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.Vertex.writeToParcel(Vertex.java:58)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.EdgesList.writeToParcel(EdgesList.java:48)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
11-23 01:52:25.384: E/AndroidRuntime(21939):    at com.csacanam.dijkstra.Vertex.writeToParcel(Vertex

EDIT:

This workaround solved my problem of circular reference

New Edge class:

```
public class Edge implements Parcelable {

    public String PKhash;
    private Vertex from;
    private Vertex target;
    private double weigth;

    public static HashMap<String, Vertex> _parentsFrom = new HashMap<String, Vertex>();
    public static HashMap<String, Vertex> _parentsTarget = new HashMap<String, Vertex>();

    public String get_PKhash() {
        /* Return a unique identifier of your Edge object here */
        return PKhash;
    }

    public Edge(Vertex from, Vertex target, double weight) {
        this.target = target;
        this.weigth = weight;
        this.from = from;
        this.PKhash=from.name+","+getWeigth()+","+target.name;
    }

    public Edge( Parcel in ) {
        this.weigth = in.readDouble();
        this.PKhash  = in.readString();
        Assert.assertTrue( (from = _parentsFrom.get( this.PKhash )) != null );
        Assert.assertTrue( (target = _parentsTarget.get( this.PKhash )) != null );
    }


    public Vertex getTarget() {
        return target;
    }

    public void setTarget(Vertex target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    public double getWeigth() {
        return weigth;
    }

    public void setWeigth(double weigth) {
        this.weigth = weigth;
    }

    public Vertex getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(Vertex from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getFrom().toString() + " -> " + weigth + " -> "
                + getTarget().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stubz
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dest.writeDouble(weigth);
        this.PKhash="";
        this.PKhash=from.name+","+getWeigth()+","+target.name;
        dest.writeString(PKhash);
        _parentsFrom.put(PKhash, from);
        _parentsTarget.put( PKhash, target);

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Edge> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Edge>() {
        public Edge createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Edge(in);
        }

        public Edge[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Edge[size];
        }
    };


}
```

New Vertex class

```
public class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex>, Parcelable {
    public final String name;
    public List<Edge> adjacencies = new ArrayList<Edge>();
    public double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    public Vertex previous;

    public Vertex(String argName) {
        name = argName;
    }

    public Vertex(Parcel in) {
        this.name = in.readString();
        this.minDistance=in.readDouble();
        Object[]aristas= in.readArray(Edge.class.getClassLoader());
        setAdjacencies(aristas);
    }

    public void addEdge(Edge e) {
        adjacencies.add(e);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public int compareTo(Vertex other) {
        return Double.compare(minDistance, other.minDistance);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeDouble(minDistance);     
        Object[] edgesArray = adjacencies.toArray();
        dest.writeArray(edgesArray);

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Vertex> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Vertex>() {
        public Vertex createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Vertex(in);
        }

        public Vertex[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Vertex[size];
        }
    };

    public void setAdjacencies(Object[] edges) {
        for (Object edge : edges) {
            if (edge instanceof Edge) {
                adjacencies.add((Edge) edge);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name.hashCode();
    }

}
```

Comment: why do you need a ArrayList which implements Parcelable? instead you can directly add Parcelable objects in ArrayList.

Comment: That was the last thing I did to try to solve my problem. Before that I had just an ArrayList<Edge implements Parcelable> for each Vertex, but when I try to send the ArrayList<Vertex> I had the same exception.

Comment: Please post the logcat

Comment: OK. I put the logcat in the post.

Comment: why are using EdgesList adjacencies in Vertex class? I found no use there...

Comment: I just modify it. Now I have just an ArrayList<Edge> but it still the same problem. I'm going to modify this change in the post.

Comment: I modified my answer. You can't have circular `Parcelable` classes. But there are workarounds like the one I suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to implement `Parcelable` in your `EdgeList`. In fact, from what I understand, you don't need `EdgeList` at all. Just modify your `Vertex` class as follows:

```
public List<Edge> adjacencies = new ArrayList<Edge>();

public Edge(Parcel in) {
    name = in.getString();
    minDistance = in.getDouble();
    adjancencies = in.readParcelableArray(Edge.getClass().getClassLoader()); 
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeDouble(minDistance);
    pc.writeParcelableArray((ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) adjacencies, flags);

}
```

I'm just not sure you can have the `Vertex` members in your `Edge` class because that might create a circular reference. Try testing it without those members first.

EDIT:

After reading some suggestions from here: [android parcelable referencing another parcelable circular dependence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176832/android-parcelable-referencing-another-parcelable-circular-dependence), I think you can try the following:

In your `Edge` class, do not write the reference to the `Vertex` members in your `writeToParcel()`. Instead, try the following:

```
public class Edge implements Parcelable {

    private Vertex from;
    private Vertex target;
    private double weigth;

    static HashMap<Long, Vertex> _parentsFrom = new HashMap<Long, Vertex>();
    static HashMap<Long, Vertex> _parentsTarget = new HashMap<Long, Vertex>();

    public long get_PKhash() { /* Return a unique identifier of your Edge object here */ }

    private ItemClass( Parcel in ) {
        (...)
        assertTrue( (from = _parentsFrom.remove( get_PKhash() )) != null );
        assertTrue( (target = _parentsTarget.remove( get_PKhash() )) != null );
    }

    public void writeToParcel( Parcel p, int args ) {
        (...)//Don't write to the parcel your from and target objects
        _parentsFrom.put( this.get_PKhash, from);
        _parentsTarget.put( this.get_PKhash, to);
    }
}
```

Note that you apparently can't have circular references in `Parcelable` implementations. This solution above is a hackish workaround and it will only work if you can ensure that each of your edge instances are uniquely identified in your application.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ricardo. I just change my class Vertex and now the attribute adjacencies is an ArrayList<Edge> but it stll the same problem. I test it without Vertex members in my Edge class but the problem is that I need in the other activity both members Vertex (from and target). For that reason I have a NullPointerException.

Comment: It doesn't work, because I need those object in the other activity. For that reason I need to send them in writeToParcel and receive them in the constructor Vertex (Parcel in)

Comment: Which objects are you talking about?

Comment: The Vertex members in Edge class (from and target). You can see my changes in the post.

Comment: I did the changes you said but now I have an AssertionErrorFailed. I'm going to add my new Edge class in the post.

Comment: @Minimal I think you need to debug your code now to understand what is happening. In your writeToParcel, is the hashmap being updated? When you create a new `Edge` instance from the Parcel, are the contents of the hashmap present? Is the the PKhash the same when you wrote and when you read it back? Go step by step and see what is going on. Please update your post later with more details. I can't really help you now if you just tell me you got a `AssertionErrorFailed`.

Comment: Thank you so much. The workaround works for me. I just had to modify some things in the code. I'm going to add in the post the modified classes (Vertex and Edge).