# Parcelable circular dependency

Tags: java, android, parcelable

- You have Class A that implements Parcelable and contains a `List` of objects of class Class B.
- Class B that implements Pracelable and contains a field of Class A.

One I implemented the Parcelable methods for each of them, I obtain a stackoverflow for the `write` methods of Parcelable which seams normal because each of those classes are calling the other in a loop.

Is there a way to avoid that ?

User Class:

```
public class User implements Parcelable {
private String mName;
private List<Collection> mCollections;
...
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeString(mName);
    out.writeList(mCollections);          // Line 76
}
...
```

Collection class

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {

    out.writeString(mTitle);
    out.writeInt(mCounter);
    out.writeSerializable(mDateRecieved);
    out.writeParcelable(mUser, flags);      //Line 205
```

Stack trace :

```
02-02 17:44:07.807 5113-5113/com.example.crysis473.cm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    java.lang.StackOverflowError
                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeString(Parcel.java:513)
                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1249)
                                                                        at com.example.crysis473.cm.Collection.writeToParcel(Collection.java:205)
                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1173)
                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:622)
                                                                        at com.example.crysis473.cm.User.writeToParcel(User.java:76)
                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
                                                                        at com.example.crysis473.cm.Collection.writeToParcel(Collection.java:205)
                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1173)
                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:622)
                                                                        at com.example.crysis473.cm.User.writeToParcel(User.java:76)
                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
                                                                        at com.example.crysis473.cm.Collection.writeToParcel(Collection.java:205)
                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
   ..........
```

Comment: Actually it's a list of objects B contained in class A, and an object of class A contains in an object B, i will try to post the code in a clean manner.

Comment: @Blackbelt I posted the code and thank you !

Comment: So a `Collection` object contains a `User`?

Comment: @cricket_007 Exactly. And It seams normal that it produces a stackOverflow because the writeParcellable() method of Collection calls the writeList() of user and one calls the other. But I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: I think you can test it with a basic Class A contains and object of Class B and Class B contains an object of Class A and both of them are Parcelables. This will cause stackoverflow.

Comment: The only reason that should happen in a cycle is if the `Collection` objects from the `User` contain that same `User`. If that is the case, you need to remodel your data.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes that's exact. Actually a Collection object have an owner (User) and that owner (same User) has a list of all its Collection(s). How do you thing I should remodel the data, I don't see any solution apart from giving a Collection an id of the User instead of the User but I will also have to search for the User by his id and it will be costly on a large scale app.

Comment: Depends what the entry point for the data is. Are you querying for all the Collections or all the Users? When you "view" a collection, you want to know the User? If so, you don't need the **entire** User object, just a reference to them like a name or id. Similarly when "viewing" a User, you don't need **all** the data from each Collection object, just they have *X* Collections which contain *N* items each or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android parcelable referencing another parcelable circular dependence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176832/android-parcelable-referencing-another-parcelable-circular-dependence)

Comment: Thank you very much, yes this is exactly what happens for me and I think I will have to change my strategy for that, because Collection view must display the name of the user and have a link to the user's profile and in the user's profile i should see the list of collections and to link to each collection. So I need all the info for link creation. I could use only primitive types but it will be very long.

Comment: Sounds like what you need is just a way to get the minimal set of data you want to display, then asynchronously fetch the rest as you need it

Comment: I also found this, https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler/issues/66
A wrapper that extends Collection.

Comment: I don't know for sure if this would work but could you exclude the `User` reference when parceling, and then derive it when unparceling?  So when you're unpacking the `User` from the parcel, go through its list of Collections, and add a reference to the User.

Comment: Actually what i did for now is to write to the parcel only the name of the user (in the Collection class) and once a Collection object has been chosen into the list, it shows the Collection object's info and the name of the User. After some other user has clicked on the name of the user owning the collection, I will make a database call and then I will import all the relevant data in order to create its profile view.