# StackOverflowError while writing Parcelable

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I have two classes, let's assume they look like these:

Movie.java

```
public class Movie implements Parcelable { 
     private int year;
     private List<Actor> actors;

     // Constructor, getters and setters, Parcelable implementation
}
```

Actor.java

```
public class Actor implements Parcelable {
    private String name;
    private Movie movie;

    // Constructor, getters and setters, Parcelable implementation
}
```

And now when I'm trying to write Movie into parcelable I get StackOverflowError:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1012)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1535)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getClassLoadingLock(ClassLoader.java:463)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:404)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java)
    atcom.example.android.data.model.Actor.writeToParcel(Actor.java:58)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1106)
    at com.example.android.data.model.Movie.writeToParcel(Movie.java:70)
```

I understand that here is problem with Nested classes, because when it tries to write Movie into Parcel, it tries to write Actor, but in Actor it tries to write Movie again.

**QUESTION**

How to avoid problem with nested classes?

Comment: Post the full error log

Comment: Added two lines, rest is the same.

Comment: this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/18177327/1320616

Comment: check this thread also https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler/issues/66

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android parcelable referencing another parcelable circular dependence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176832/android-parcelable-referencing-another-parcelable-circular-dependence)

Answer (score 0):

Don't store the `Movie` inside the `Actor`. The two-way relationship between them is creating the error.

Also, it doesn't even make sense that the `Actor` should store a `Movie`. A real life actor can be in many movies, or none, or maybe they only do TV acting.

Comment: Of come on, it's hypothetic. I know that it's creating error, I wrote about it. How to deal with such model structure?

Comment: This is a parent-child relationship. The best way to do it is to only store the child in the parent, and not the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Implement an [Externalizable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) instead. Then use [writeObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutput.html#writeObject%28java.lang.Object%29) to serialize the references with account for object identity.

Java serialization protocol was designed to handle circular interdependencies between objects. Parcelables do not support those by design — attempting to hack in such support would pointlessly duplicate work, already done by creators of `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`. Note, that I am not suggesting to implement Serializable (which is slow, because of being reflection-based), but rather implementing Externalizable, which is basically the same thing as Parcelable, except it plays well with serialization.

`ObjectOutputStream` itself is neither Serializable nor Parcelable, but you can direct it to `ByteArrayOutputStream` and pass resulting byte array around:

```
public static byte[] serialize(Externalizable object) {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    ObjectOutputStream objectStream = null;
    try {
        objectStream = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);
        objectStream.writeObject(object);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        if (objectStream != null) {
            try { objectStream.close(); } catch (IOException ignored) {}
        }
    }

    return buffer.toByteArray();
}

public static <T extends Externalizable> T deserialize(byte[] bytes) {
    ObjectInputStream objectStream = null;
    try {
        objectStream = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
        return (T) objectStream.readObject();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        if (objectStream != null) {
            try { objectStream.close(); } catch (IOException ignored) {}
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how your classes would look now:

Actor:

```
class Actor implements Externalizable {
  private String name;
  private Movie movie;

  public Actor(String name, Movie movie) {
    this.name = name;
    this.movie = movie;
  }

  // required by Externalizable contract
  public Actor() {
  }

  @Override
  public void readExternal(ObjectInput input) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    name = input.readUTF();
    movie = (Movie) input.readObject();
  }

  @Override
  public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput output) throws IOException {
    output.writeUTF(name);
    output.writeObject(movie);
  }

  ...
}
```

Movie:

```
class Movie implements Externalizable {
  private List<Actor> actors;

  private int year;

  public Movie(int year) {
    this.year = year;

    actors = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public void addActors(Actor... actors) {
    Collections.addAll(this.actors, actors);
  }

  // required by Externalizable contract
  public Movie() {
  }

  @Override
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public void readExternal(ObjectInput input) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    year = input.read();
    actors = (List<Actor>) input.readObject();
  }

  @Override
  public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput output) throws IOException {
    output.write(year);
    output.writeObject(actors);
  }

  ...
}
```

I have just tested on my device and was able to successfully pass cross-referencing Movie/Actor across Activities via Intent.

Comment: Sorry, it's Android.

Comment: Looks like you haven't really understood my suggestion. I have added some example code, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This will create an infinite loop while writing the `Movie` object to a `Parcelable`, if you really need the reference to the `Movie` from within the `Actor` you could try adding an ID to the `Movie` class and give this ID to the `Actor`, later you could use this ID to track the corresponding `Movie`, altho Im not sure if this still meets your requirements. Anyway, using a circular reference is strongly disencouraged in OO languages.