# Passing Parcelable from Activity A to Activity B - getExtra is null

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

When I use `Intent` to pass a `Parcelable` object from Activity A to Activity B, B activity getExtra is null. Following my code:

```
class A(var id: Int, var name: String,var bList:MutableList<B>) : Parcelable {
    override fun writeToParcel(p0: Parcel, p1: Int) {
        p0.writeInt(id)
        p0.writeString(name)
        p0.writeTypedList(bList)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
            parcel.readInt(),
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.createTypedArrayList(B.CREATOR)

    )

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<A> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): A {
            return A(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<A?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

class B

```
class B(var id: Int, var name: String, var a: A) : Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
            parcel.readInt(),
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.readParcelable(A::class.java.classLoader))

    override fun writeToParcel(p0: Parcel, p1: Int) {
        p0.readInt()
        p0.readString()
        p0.readParcelable<A>(A.javaClass.classLoader)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<B> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): B {
            return B(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<B?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

I use intent to pass data：

```
val list = mutableListOf<B>()
val a = A(1,"A",list)
val b1 = B(1,"B1",a)
val b2 = B(2,"B2",a)
list.add(b1)
list.add(b2)
val intent = Intent()
intent.setClass(context, AboutActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("frank",a)
startActivity(intent)
```

I am using following code to retrieve data:

```
val bundle = intent.extras
val a:A = bundle.getParcelable("frank")
```

Is this data structure a dead loop when write Parcelable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues that you're running into.

First, the `writeToParcel()` function on class `B` is reading instead of writing. You most likely meant to do this:

```
override fun writeToParcel(p0: Parcel, p1: Int) {
    p0.writeInt(id)
    p0.writeString(name)
    p0.writeParcelable(a, 0)
}
```

Once you make that change, you'll run into the second issue: you'll get a stack overflow error because your models have dependencies on each other. `A` depends on a list of `B` objects, each of which has a reference to the `A` object again. This [circular dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) is not a supported by Android's parceling code.

There was a [bug ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36921097) opened about this many years ago, but its status is marked as `Won't Fix (Infeasible)`.

There are some workarounds mentioned in [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176832/android-parcelable-referencing-another-parcelable-circular-dependence), but in general, it's best to avoid circular dependencies if at all possible.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got the stack overflow error in my project, so I made this test demo to show this issue. I will discuss with backend to change their json structure, and thanks again!

Comment: Sounds good, @Frank.Wang!  If this answered your question (and it sounds like it did, based on your comment), then please also consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: OK, this is my fisrt question on stackoverflow, I will accept.thanks@Dave Leeds